# adding attribute to select using parent's data- attribue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In a html page inside div I have a html select with options, below is my markup:

```
<div class="field vert Display" data-group="HI">
    <select aria-required="true" name="InsuranceFor">
        <option value="">I want cover for</option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Couple">Couple</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to add an attribute to select using parent div's data-group attribute, I tried teh below code but it do not add `require=""` in `select` code. I have confirm function is executed on call but it do not add anything at all. Can you please guide me how to do that ?

```
function ShowForm()
    {               
            $("[data-group=HI] select").attr("required")
    }
```

I also has tried                 `$("[data-group=HI] > select").attr("required")` but no effect. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, It should work for you

```
$('[data-group="HI"]').find("select").attr("required",true);
```

Just for first select do following

```
$('[data-group="HI"]').find("select:first").attr("required",true);
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/106/)

Comment: thanks, can I control it to apply just on first Select under Div with this data- attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

as stated in the documentation:

As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method.

```
$('[data-group="HI"]').find("select:first").prop("required",true);
```

Comment: `attr` is not deprecated, it's not a good tool for modifying boolean attributes!